# Excel Rank - Skipping Ranks

Tags: excel, excel-formula, rank

I am trying to have a RANK formula that does not skip any whole numbers (e.g. 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

[Screenshot showing the current rank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTWVS.png)

I have this formula that is dividing the number down into decimals which seems to work for the most part, and then a separate formula using RANK.EQ to rank them. However, while it has worked for 95% of the data, there is one bit of my dashboard where it is skipping 6 (1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10)

[Formula used to creat decimals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFa4e.png)

```
=IFERROR((COLUMN(INDIRECT(LEFT([@[Client Name]])&"1"))/1000000),0)+(SUM(SWITCH([@YTD],CurrentFY,(SWITCH(COUNTIFS($AG$2:$AG2,[@[Client Name]],$AJ$2:$AJ2,CurrentFY),1,COUNTIFS([Client Name],[@[Client Name]],[YTD],CurrentFY,[Proposal Type],{"Quote Re-Work","Amendment Re-Work"}),0)),0)))
```

[Formula used to get ranking list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXvpt.png)

```
=RANK.EQ([@[Total Customer (FY YTD) - RE-WORKS '#]],[Total Customer (FY YTD) - RE-WORKS '#])
```

Any ideas why it is skipping out 6? The rest of the columns work and there is a large dataset so not sure how this is a problem - any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Without you showing any results so we could see, questions like "are there two at 5? come to mind.

Comment: I have added in another photo showing the current rank

Comment: It's better to show some sample data including digits that cause your problem. You can use https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables to paste your data and generate a table you could post in your question, so we can copy paste, rather than type it over from a picture. Make sure to also add your expected results with given sample data.